# Wordpress Genesis Framework Custom Header

Tags: php, wordpress, header, genesis

I have come across an issue I can't seem to resolve through browsing these and other forums.

I am using the following code to use my pages featured image as a header background image and the code below that to generate a custom site title and description.

What is happening is that the custom Site Title and Description are showing up below the featured header images. I am assuming this is because the header image is now located at yogaweb_featured_header and not genesis_header, while my code for the custom site title and description is still trying to place it at genesis_header and not at yogaweb_featured_header.

Any suggestions or answers would be a huge help.

Featured Image PHP

```
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );

add_action( 'genesis_header', 'yogaweb_featured_header' );
//ADD FEATURED IMAGE TO HEADER
function yogaweb_featured_header() {

if( is_singular( 'page' ) ) {

global $post;

$size = 'full-size';
$default_attr = array(
'class' => "aligncenter attachment-$size $size",
'alt' => $post->post_title,
'title' => $post->post_title,
);

printf( '<div class="example">%s</div>', genesis_get_image( array( 'size' =>  $size, 'attr' => $default_attr ) ) );

}

}
// CHANGE DIMENSIONS BELOW TO FIT YOUR THEME
add_image_size('cover', TRUE);

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_image_sizes_choose' );

function my_custom_image_sizes_choose( $sizes ) {
 $custom_sizes = array(
'cover' => 'cover',
);
return array_merge( $sizes, $custom_sizes );
}
```

Custom Title and Descriptions PHP

```
// Custom Site Title
// Filter the title with a custom function
add_filter('genesis_seo_title', 'yoga_site_title' );

// Add additional custom style to site header
function yoga_site_title( $title ) {

    // Change $custom_title text as you wish
$custom_title = '<span class="site-title">Yogaisaweso.me</span>';


// Don't change the rest of this on down

// If we're on the front page or home page, use `h1` heading, otherwise us a `p` tag
$tag = ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ? 'h1' : 'h1';

// Compose link with title
$inside = sprintf( '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', trailingslashit( home_url() ), esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ), $custom_title );

// Wrap link and title in semantic markup
$title = sprintf ( '<%s class="site-title" itemprop="headline">%s</%s>', $tag, $inside, $tag );
return $title;

}
// First line of Header text
//* Remove the tag line / site description
remove_action( 'genesis_site_description', 'genesis_seo_site_description' );

add_action( 'genesis_site_description', 'child1_seo_site_description' );
/**
* Change the site description (also called tagline)
* to include html code.
* Remove description, add whatever change you want to make.
* Then add description back to header.
*/

function child1_seo_site_description() {

echo '<h2 id="description1">ELEVATED THROUGH COMMUNITY</h2>';

}

// Second Line of Header Content
add_action( 'genesis_site_description', 'child2_seo_site_description' );
/**
* Change the site description (also called tagline)
* to include html code.
* Remove description, add whatever change you want to make.
* Then add description back to header.
*
* @author Terry Collins
* @since 1.0.0
*/
function child2_seo_site_description() {

echo '<div class="center-icon"><div class="one-third first" id="description2">
  <i id="fa-head" class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-3x"></i><br>CREATE</div>
 <div class="one-third" id="description2">
  <i id="fa-head" class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></i><br>INSPIRE</div><div class="one-third" id="description2">
  <i id="fa-head" class="fa fa-tree fa-3x"></i><br>GROW</div></div>';

 }
```

Thanks in advance for all help

Comment: I realized my image wasn't being placed as a background image, however when I changed the my function.php file to load it as a bg image the same thing occurs. I am totally lost here

Comment: I gave up and just did it using css background images targeting page-id's